# Is there a standard way to get LOAD INFILE working?

Tags: mysql

Load data infile has always been a pain in the ass to set up and there does not seem to be standard way to get it to work but I have always been able to get it to work ….eventually except now.

I am struggling with

```
Error Code: 29. File '/loadinfile/file.csv' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

The system is as follows:

MySQL version 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
Ubuntu 22.04

The load file directory is owned by mysql:mysql and same with the file and I have tried chmod 757 and even 777

In the config file I have tried the following variations:

```
secure_file_priv = "/loadinfile/"

secure_file_priv = '/loadinfile/'

secure_file_priv = ""

secure_file_priv = ''
```

The following is also set :

```
[mysqld]

local-infile = 1

[client]

loose-local-infile=1
```

Changing

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/loadinfile/file.csv' INTO TABLE table
```

to

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/loadinfile/file.csv' INTO TABLE table
```

changes the error message to:

```
Error Code: 2. File '\loadinfile\file.csv' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I`m assuming the database is hosted on your machine? localhost correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error Code: 2. File '\loadinfile\file.csv' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
```

Above message indicates that your directory where the file is located is wrong! You must define the full path:

For example In Mac If your file resides on Desktop,It must be like this :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/computer_name/Desktop/filename.file_extension' INTO TABLE table
```

In windows

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\computer_name\Desktop\filename.file_extension' INTO TABLE table
```

I hope It solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Error Code: 2. indicates invalid file path. Keep the **LOCAL** INFILE option and either specify the full path of the CSV file or make sure the CSV file path is correct. give it a try with Full path and see if it solves the problem or not.
From [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

> If LOCAL is specified, the file must be located on the client host.
> The client program reads the file, locating it as follows:
>
> If the file name is an absolute path name, the client program uses it
> as given.
>
> If the file name is a relative path name, the client program looks for
> the file relative to its invocation directory

Edited
Make sure your `mysqld.cnf` or your main MySQL config file has the following variables

```
secure_file_priv = ""
local_infile=1
```

And your Global variable `local_infile` is OFF, turn it ON.
you can check that if you run this query

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

if it is OFF, turn it ON

And lastly, Make sure you restart your SQL service to reflect the changes. you can do that if you execute

```
service mysql restart
```

Hope that solves your problem